# How to get around redundant records when joining two tables on the same DATETIME?

Tags: php

I am performing a left join on the forumPosts and PostImages on DATETIME. I am performing this join so that I can access the items stored in each of those tables. I am getting redundant posts which are the product of all combinations of that join because those records have the same time. The redundant posts all have the according `topic_id` specific to each of the discussion areas because they derive from that single record's all possible combinations . I am not getting redundant posts to my `forumPosts` and `PostImages` tables in the database because the error is in the query in `view_topic` file. If I could please get help perfecting my query/join so that the records are more specifically targeted. I am wondering if there is a way to specifically identify the records with the same time. Please see the screen capture below of the forum with redundant posts.

This code is for the view topic page (view_topic.php). Please note that I execute a query to join ImagePosts with forumPosts which should return just the records with matching topic_id. I now believe I am getting all the products of the join on DATETIME. I need to know how I can restrict that query to the specific records.

```
    $query5 = 'SELECT * FROM forumPosts LEFT JOIN PostImages ON 
    forumPosts.DATETIME = PostImages.ImageDATETIME where 
    topic_id="'.$tid.'"ORDER BY replyIndex ASC';


    $statement = $db->prepare($query5);
    $statement->execute();

    //count returned rows
    $count = $statement->rowCount();
    echo "<h1>".$count."</h1>";

    $posts = $statement->fetchAll();

    $statement->closeCursor();
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($posts as $post){
    if ($post['post_type'] == "r"){
    $post_id = $post['post_id'];
    echo "<tr bgcolor='beige'><td>". $post['post_author'] . "</td >
    <td>". $post['post_title']."</td><td>". $post['post_body']; 
    if (!empty($post['ID']) && ($post['type']== 'i')) {
        echo "<img src='getImage.php?id=".$post['ID']."'>";
    } elseif (!empty($post['ID']) && ($post['type']== 'm')) {
        echo '<audio controls>'; 
        echo '<source 
    src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.base64_encode($post['image']).'"‌​>';
        echo '</audio>';
    } elseif (!empty($post['ID']) && ($post['type']== '3')) {
        echo '<audio controls>'; 
        echo '<source 
    src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.base64_encode($post['image']).'"‌​>';
        echo '</audio>';
        echo '<p>Buy the full track with PayPal:</p>'. $post['URL'];
    }

    echo "</td><td>". $post['topic_id']."</td><td>". $post['DATETIME']. 
    "</td><td>". $post['replyIndex']. "</td><td>".$post['post_type']."
    </td>";
```

[image: Capture of my forum showing redundant posts]

[image: image showing PostImages]
[image: Image showing forumPosts]

Comment: So, the "ID" is primary key here? I can't see where are you checking whether there exists a row with a given "name" column before inserting.

Comment: ID is primary key in PostImages table. Post_id is primary key in forumPost table. I am moving the 'name', 'description' and 'itemNum' to the other tables.

Comment: I think i know the problem. Because I am joining on of the DATETIME with all the DATETIMEs being the same I am getting all the products of there combination. I need to figure out how to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add another join condition to the code:
$query5 = 'SELECT * FROM forumPosts LEFT JOIN PostImages ON forumPosts.DATETIME = PostImages.ImageDATETIME AND 
forumPosts.topic_id = PostImages.topic_id_image where topic_id="'.$tid.'"ORDER BY replyIndex ASC';
Thanks for helping me figure it out!